# Convert ArrayBuffer to String in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, decoding, arraybuffer

I have an ArrayBuffer that is a PDF, but **I'm trying to convert it to a string (Extract the Pdf text).** I'm not too familiar, so I'm not really sure the reasoning how ArrayBuffers, binary strings, or what base64 does in terms of files.

**Here's my ArrayBuffer:**

```
ArrayBuffer
byteLength: 158265
```

Comment: Converting the buffer to a string most certainly will **not** "extract the PDF text" from the content. PDF is a complicated file format.

Comment: Is it possible to extract the PDF text from the content? If so, what would the steps involved?

Comment: It's quite involved; really you'd need some software designed to do that; the concept doesn't really even make sense in general because a PDF file can have all sorts of complicated textual layout instructions, images, tables, etc.

Comment: Google for Javascript PDF parsing libraries. That should be the right direction. Note that you won't have one block of text though, you will have a number of individual lines or otherwise blocks of text plus possibly images, shapes, etc, and you need to make sense of those based on their positions on the page.

Comment: I've used [pdf2json](https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json) in the past with good results.

Comment: The only problem with pdf2json is that it uses fs, which doesn't work with React. Trying to see if I can find a library that uses native HTML methods

Comment: Like with FileReader or something along those lines